# Pause and resume a thread c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to pause a thread in my function which will then be resumed when a button is clicked. Windows form application

```
    private readonly AutoResetEvent mre = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    public void InstINP( int IntAcc)
    {
        BtnInp.Enabled = true; //enable text box
        MessageBox.Show("Please input a value");

        mre.WaitOne();
    }

    void BtnInp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblACC.Text = TxtInput.Text; //print to accumulator label
        BtnInp.Enabled = false; //disable button

        mre.Set();
    }
```

This is what my code looks like. I want to pause where it says mre.WaitOne(); and resume where it says mre.Set().
However, when this code runs I am unable to press any buttons on my program or interact with the program, meaning I am unable to resume the program.

Comment: If you run InstINP on the UI thread then it is logical that nothing can be done. You need at least one extra thread but by the looks of it that will over complicate stuff for you and give you new (but better) headaches. Can't you just show a label instead of that messagebox and disable all other controls?

Comment: Just to be complete, is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: You're trying to do something very strange. Explain *why* you think that pausing a thread is the right thing to do. Odds are pretty good that there is some better way to solve the problem that you really have.  Also, **ask a question when you post a question**. So far you've just told a story: you paused a thread, and since it is the thread that unpauses itself, it stays paused forever. That's a story, not a question. What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

- `mre.WaitOne()` does pause the thread.
- `mre.Set()` does resume the thread.

The additional fact you probably already knew:

- A paused thread doesn't do any processing.

And the thing you failed to think about:

- **You are pausing the thread that processes button clicks.**

If you want to pause some bit of logic, instead of an entire thread, you can use a C# task for that:

- Create a TaskCompletionSource, say `tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>()`
- Pause with `await tcs.Task;`
- Resume with `tcs.SetResult(true);`

Use of `await` will pause the operation in progress and return to processing other events, like button clicks.

The way this works is that the C# compiler automatically splits up your code into multiple function calls, so the first one can return to the message dispatch loop, and the remaining code can be called later when the Task completes.  The `await` keyword marks where the compiler will do this splitting.

Important note: `TaskCompletionSource` cannot be reset and reused like `AutoResetEvent`.  You'll have to construct a new one for each pause/resume cycle.

Comment: Would this code be put in the same place that the corresponding mre code is used or is the taskcompletionsource defined within the INP function

Comment: @BethanLaw: It will have to be declared as a class member, so that your other method can call its `SetResult` method.  But you can construct it inside the INP method if you like.

Comment: a more interesting questions is - what are you actually trying to do. What are you trying to pause?